# Uncaught ReferenceError: changeLayer is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to make function toogle layer using java script, this is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function changeLayer(idSelections)
    {
        if (idSelections === "Agro Industri")
        {
            if (document.getElementById("AI").checked === true)
            {
                if(AI.getMap() === null)
                {
                    AI.setMap(map);
                }
            }
            if (document.getElementById("AI").checked === false)
            {
                AI.setMap(null); // layer set off
            }
        }
    };
});
```

and this is the HTML :

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Agro Industri" value="Agro Industri" id="AI" onClick="changeLayer(this.value)"> Layer AI<br/>
  </div>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

but every i try to check/uncheck the checkbox, i always got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: changeLayer is not defined`. could someone help to to fix this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the function outside document ready. Script inside document ready will run after the DOM finished rendered into page.

```
<script>
function changeLayer(idSelections)
{
    if (idSelections === "Agro Industri")
    {
        if (document.getElementById("AI").checked === true)
        {
            if(AI.getMap() === null)
            {
                AI.setMap(map);
            }
        }
        if (document.getElementById("AI").checked === false)
        {
            AI.setMap(null); // layer set off
        }
    }
};
</script>
```